# Compile error in hidden module : This document

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I am getting the following error when I open a Word document in MS Word 2007 on Windows 2007 machine.

> Compile error in hidden module : This document

This document contains macros, and it works fine on another machine.

I think this error began to occur after some security updates.

Is this an OS or MS Word security issue?

Comment: You will need to provide far more information than that for us to be able to help you, including the code in question.

Comment: Code is perfect because it run fine on other machine, i thing this is OS or Ms Office related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code that runs when the document is open.  It is trying to use a procedure that can not find or is not defined.

If you can use it correctly in some machines but in others not, then probably the machine with problems:
  a) Doesnt have a necesary AddIn/Library

or

b) Doesnt have access to the network location where the AddIn or Library is.

Comment: I found solution from this link:http:        www.lessanvaezi.com/delete-exd-files-to-fix-object-library-invalid-error/

Answer (score 0):

I recall seeing this message once a year or more ago - I believe the issue was related to trying to run it on a 64 bit version of office, while the original document was produced on in 32 bit.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

word error "compile error in hidden module: This Document"

-- IMPORTANT -- 
The first part of this is based on other peoples solutions [credits at bottom of page], the last part is my solutions based on it. I have noticed that a lot of people a little scared to go playing with computers and things they don't quite understand giving them issues in following complexed instuctions so I have tried to dumb it down a little hoping it will more helpful, and that will make it a little long winded for some.

Finding the location of the winword.exe file in YOUR system, I found it in this location [Yours may or may not be in the same location] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE".

once you find it right click in the windows address bar and "copy address as text" you will or I ended up with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12" as it will not copy the folder contents this is GOOD. so you need to add "\" and the "winword.exe" in the EXACT case used i.e uppercase use uppercase same for lowercase.

Before I start lets save some confusion "enter without the double quotation marks - used only to highlight what text to use."
Also so we don't break anything that we have time and effort on open up Word and make a new blank doc and save it as "blank doc" we will use it later.

1.) Now we need to break down the location address, we pretty much use the bits between the "\" and add a cd with a space as below, on the last one "winword.exe or WINWORD.EXE" [depends on what case they used] we add the "/a" without the "cd space" prefix. So just open up a new "NOTE PAD" or something similar to use for this as Word NEED'S to be closed when we enter the last command into "CMD"(*1).

So this address:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE

Should look like this:
cd Program Files (x86)
cd Microsoft Office
cd Office12
WINWORD.EXE /a

2.) MAKE SURE that Mircosoft Word is CLOSED!

3.) Use both the windows key & the "R" key together it will open the "Run" box. Type in "cmd" and hit enter.

4.) The "CMD" box will open up and mostly display "C:\" but if it doesn't it is pretty much who care's at this point! Don't stress out.

5.) Now you simply follow the instruction below with cut and past one at a time into the "CMD" box and hit enter. Once you have done this open the blank word doc you made, if there is NO error this are good so far.

If it does NOT say "C:\" in the "CMD" box type in "cd C:\" and hit enter.

Once it is displaying "C:\" type in "dir" and enter.

It should now display [using my location obviously this should match yours not mine :)]: about 50 to god know how many DIR's, it will be a long list..

cut & paste [yes without quotes]: "cd Program Files (x86)" hit "enter"
It should now display: C:\Program Files (x86)>

cut & paste: "cd Microsoft Office" hit "enter"
It should now display: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office>

cut & paste: "cd Office12" hit "enter"
It should now display:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12>

cut & paste: "WINWORD.EXE /a" hit "enter"
Word should NOW be open

NOTE: You may be able to use the whole address at once but it did not work for me "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EX /a"

6.) Next you need to find you WORD startup folder mine was in this location "C:\Users\noel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP"
You can find this by typing "%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\Startup" in the Windows Explorer Address bar and pressing Enter (*2).

7.) Ok the Word startup folder should be open in front of you now if it has anything it, [I am hoping that is does or this wont work sorry] you need to right click on the desktop and make a new folder and name it something "Holding word startup" open it and go back to the Word startup folder click it to make it the current window. Now use "Ctrl + A" keys to select all of the contents then "Ctrl + C" to copy them. Now go back to the new folder you made [Holding word startup] and click in it and use "Ctrl + V" to paste the contents inside the folder, once you are sure that the contents in both folders are the same. Go back to the Word startup folder and "Ctrl + A" to select all and "Delete" to yes delete all the contents.

My Word startup had a file called "WordTalk.dot" in it. Which once open only had the word "hello" in it.

8.) Now with the Word startup folder empty double click on the "blank doc" you made earlier to open it and test to see if the error "compile error in hidden module: This Document" has vanished.

9.) This fixed my issue and I only had the one file "WordTalk.dot" in the startup and it was a word doc with only one word in it I deleted it! But I know how to recover that file if I need to if things go wrong tomorrow. If you do not or don't understand what is in your backup copy you made of the Word startup folder "Holding word startup" DO NOT delete it just move it somewhere safe, just incase.

Noel

---------------- References ------------------

(*1) Microsoft Support.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/921541/how-to-troubleshoot-problems-that-occur-when-you-start-or-use-word

(*2) Graham Mayor.

http://www.gmayor.com/what_to_do_when_word_crashes.htm